# selenium java add cookies

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cookies

Eclipse giving error,`Date` is deprecated.Can anyone please help to sort this out, My code is following
Using stored cookie to login into the script.

```
File file = new File("Cookies.data");                           
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);                           
BufferedReader Buffreader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);                         
String strline;         
while((strline=Buffreader.readLine())!=null){                                   
    String Tokenizertoken = newStringTokenizer(strline,";");                                    
    while(token.hasMoreTokens()){                   
        String name = token.nextToken();                    
        String value = token.nextToken();                   
        String domain = token.nextToken();                  
        String path = token.nextToken();                    
        Date expiry = null;                         
        String val; 
        if(!(val=token.nextToken()).equals("null")){        
            expiry = new Date(val);                 
        }       
        Boolean isSecure = new Boolean(token.nextToken()).booleanValue();       
        Cookie ck = new Cookie(name,value,domain,path,expiry,isSecure);                                                                 
        driver.manage().addCookie(ck); // This will add the stored 
                                       cookie to your current session                   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Calendar instead of Date as Date is deprecated

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date =  calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying, but Unfortunately, I didn't get exactly. how can I add on the above code, can you please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I have " Date expiry = null;". and then adding string and calling date.  
  String val; 
        if(!(val=token.nextToken()).equals("null")){        
            expiry = new Date(val).... I shall be thankful to you.